# How can I set the LISTBOX tooltip through XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list box in WPF as under

```
<ListBox Name="lstName" DisplayMemberPath ="ListName" ToolTip="{Binding Path=ListName}" />
```

**My requirement is that what ever items I am displaying in the listbox, should also appear in the tooltip. i.e. if the items are say "Item1", "Item2" etc. then when the user will point(hover) to "Item1" through mouse, the toolltip should display "Item1". Same for others**

So my DisplayMemberPath is set to the Property which I am supposed to display (and it is coming properly). However, the tooltip is not coming at all.

The entity is as under

```
public class ItemList
{
  public string ListName { get; set; }
}
```

The binding is happening as under

```
this.lstName.ItemsSource = GetData(); // Assume that the data is coming properly
```

Comment: Have you checked output of VS? since binding is not thorwing any exception info about binding is there

Comment: Actually , no tooltip is displaying..

Comment: please don't put things like "(WPF, C#)" in your title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Sure I will take care of the same from the next time I post the questions. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of setting the ToolTip property on the ListBox, set it on the ListBoxItems by applying a style:

```
<ListBox Name="lstName" DisplayMemberPath="ListName">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ListName}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

That way, each ListBoxItem will have its own tooltip that displays the value for that item.

Since you are setting the ItemsSource on the ListBox directly, you probably haven't set a DataContext, so the Binding won't work there.  If you do set the DataContext to the list, then that binding would display the currently selected item as the tooltip no matter where the mouse was on the ListBox.

Comment: @priyanka: I updated my answer with a little more explanation.  Did it answer your question?  You were setting a tooltip on the ListBox, so it was binding relative to the DataContext of the ListBox, which I'm guessing was null.  Setting it on the ListBoxItem will bind relative to the DataContext of the ListBoxItem, which will be the item from your ItemsSource list.