# Getting index of listboxitem in WPF listbox ( system.windows.control.listbox ) using mouse pointer position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, mouseenter

I am a newbie to WPF. I have developed an WPF UserControl application in which I have a listbox. Height of the listbox is restricted to 400 just to get vertical scroll-bar. In this listbox I have more than 100 items. Now for each of these Item I have to display some tooltip for which I need the index of item in a listbox which is under current mouse pointer. So, for this I have added a MouseOver event like MouseEnter.

Here is snippet of My Xaml code

```
<ListBox Name="AllProjects" TabIndex="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="400" MouseEnter="AllProjects_MouseEnter"> </ListBox>
```

Here is backend C# code

```
 private void AllProjects_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point Position = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender); 
    }
```

So, I am getting the position of the of the mouse pointer wrt my current listbox but real problem is converting this position to index of the item in listbox. As I am using **system.windows.control.listbox** and not **System.Windows.Forms.listbox**, I do not have  **IndexFromPoint** method. As my listbox is scrollable vertically, If I try to develop a logic to get index it will get messy. I just wanted to know if there is any easy way to get listboxitem index in this case. **AllProjects** is the name of my listbox. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the index item? How is it related to displaying a tooltip?

Comment: @Ucodia : Actually every listbox item need to have different tool tip and I have a dictionary which stores item name and relevant tooltip. For this I need an index.

Comment: Ok. Can this tooltip text be added to a property of the items in the list?

Comment: Actually I am newbie to WPF so really not getting the idea. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: What type of objects are you adding to this list?

Comment: I am adding file names as the key and there actual path on the local system as the value. Both are simple strings only. So, I want this value of each item, to be a tooltip. SO every item will have a different tool tip. To fetch this tooltip, I need an index item to look, which I am struggling to get from mouseover event.

Comment: Ok I posted an answer that should help achieving your current goal. I must say there is much more elegant ways to accomplish this in WPF but I guess this is a good starter and that you will learn the "good ways" on your path to learn XAML with C# :)

Comment: @Ucodia : Thanks a lot for the reply. I will try this. Hope I will learn more and more about XAML and C# :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the MouseEnter event you should hook on the SelectionChanged event. Then simply get the index of your item throught the SelectedIndex property from the ListBox.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="AllProjects" SelectionChanged="AllProjects_SelectionChanged" />
```

C#:

```
private void AllProjects_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = this.AllProjects.SelectedIndex;
}
```

But this is quite a "quick and dirty" way of achieving your current goal. If you really want to get into WPF, try to forget most of the techniques you used in other UI framework such as Windows Forms and start learning about the power of [WPF Databinding](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html) and the beauty of [XAML data templating](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368537/2132796

You don't need to grab the selected index property of the listbox. You just have to use an item template like linked above.

I would also recommend to follow Ucodias advice and learn something about databinding.