# Image title tips not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

What is wrong with the following XAML?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Lookup">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding History, Converter={StaticResource LookupHistoryConvertor}}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding AssignmentTypeImage}"
                                ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
                                Margin="2" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It does not show a tooltip as expected:

[image: Tooltip]

Each image should have it's own tooltip if possible. If it can't be done then I will investigate doing a multiline tooltip on the cell itself to reflect the data for the images displayed.

But why does not XAML not work?

Update: The `ToolTip` in this column works fine:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Last Used For">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        ToolTip="{Binding LastUsedTooltip}">
                <Image Source="{Binding LastUsedImage}" Margin="2,2,5,2" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastUsed}" Margin="2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But in that column I only have one image and have set the tip on the `StackPanel`. So the context is different.

Update: I can show a tip if I associated it with the `StackPanel` in the `ItemsPanel`. But not each image.

Update: I can't seem to get the suggestion to work. No change:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Lookup">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding History, Converter={StaticResource LookupHistoryConvertor}}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding AssignmentTypeImage}" Margin="2" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Where did you define the `tooltip` in your XAML?

Comment: I don't actually see where you have `ToolTip=""` in your code. Did you miss something?

Comment: @pay Oops. That was odd. Updated.

Comment: Just to diagnose whether it's a code-behind or GUI issue,  if you just hard-code something into the tooltip, say `ToolTip="This is a tooltip!"`, and then check that, does it work as expected?

Comment: @pay Nothing displays

Comment: That might suggest something is over top of those image controls. Is there anything overlayed on top of them that has a higher z-index?

Comment: @pay I haven't personally set the z-index for any controls on the window.

Comment: I was just testing quickly in the WPF application I have open in front of me. I have an image control that has a transparent button overlayed on it. If I have a tooltip set on the image, it will not work because the button is on top of it. I have not set and z-indexes myself either, so just placing something over those controls would be enough for the tooltip to not display.

Comment: @pay Please see updated question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the LISTBOX tooltip through XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368510/how-can-i-set-the-listbox-tooltip-through-xaml)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle the post Chris W linked is not exactly what you're asking but it is definitely related. I would take a look at that accepted answer and try a similar template but for the Image control as oppose to 'ListBoxItem'.

Comment: Nah ListBoxItem inherits from ContentControl so has it's own hit test visibility as the parent. The linked dupe should work fine.

Comment: @ChrisW.Please see updated question.

Comment: @ChrisW.I was a muppet. My property is called **Tooltip** and not **ToolTip**!